# react date range calculate (opened business hours)

Tags: reactjs, date, range, momentjs, overlap

I would like to calculate for how long my business is open during the week.
I've got an array of hours slots of my week.
The problem is that some of them overlap, and calculation is wrong.
Here is an example :

In my day, I have 3 ranges like this :

[image]

And array is like this :

```
const obj = [
  {
    startDate: 'Mon Apr 19 2021 08:30:00 GMT+0200',
    endDate: 'Mon Apr 19 2021 12:00:00 GMT+0200'
  },
  {
    startDate: 'Mon Apr 19 2021 09:00:00 GMT+0200',
    endDate: 'Mon Apr 19 2021 12:30:00 GMT+0200'
  },
  {
    startDate: 'Mon Apr 19 2021 09:30:00 GMT+0200',
    endDate: 'Mon Apr 19 2021 13:00:00 GMT+0200'
  },
  ...
]
```

(this is a little example, because I have others intersections in my week)

Finally, what I've done, but which is wrong with intersections is this :

```
const total = (obj.length > 0)
? obj.map(item => {
    const end = moment(item.endDate)
    const start = moment(item.startDate)
    const duration = moment.duration(end.diff(start))
    return duration.asHours()
  }).reduce((a, b) => a + b)
: 0
```

Here result is 10,5 hours : it's wrong
I have no idea how can I consider overlaps range to get real result : work from 8:30 to 13:00 so good result is 4,5 hours.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let entries = [
  {
    startDate: "2021-04-19 09:30:00",
    endDate: "2021-04-19 13:00:00"
  },
  {
    startDate: "2021-04-19 08:30:00",
    endDate: "2021-04-19 12:00:00"
  },
  {
    startDate: "2021-04-19 09:00:00",
    endDate: "2021-04-19 12:30:00"
  },
  {
    startDate: "2021-04-19 15:00:00",
    endDate: "2021-04-19 17:30:00"
  }
];

entries = entries
  .map((obj) => ({
    startDate: moment(obj.startDate).valueOf(),
    endDate: moment(obj.endDate).valueOf()
  }))
  .sort((obj1, obj2) => obj1.startDate - obj2.startDate);
const ranges = [entries[0]];

for (let obj of entries) {
  let lastRange = ranges[ranges.length - 1];
  if (obj.startDate <= lastRange.endDate) {
    ranges[ranges.length - 1].startDate = Math.min(
      lastRange.startDate,
      obj.startDate
    );
    ranges[ranges.length - 1].endDate = Math.max(
      lastRange.endDate,
      obj.endDate
    );
  } else {
    ranges.push(obj);
  }
}

console.log(
  ranges.map((range) => (range.endDate - range.startDate) / (1000 * 60 * 60))
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```

**[Original answer]**

Assuming that `startDate` and `endDate` in every object in your array has the same day, a possible approach is the following

```
const daysHours = {};

obj.forEach((item) => {
  const day = moment(item.endDate).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
  daysHours[day] = daysHours[day] || { min: 60 * 24, max: 0 };
  daysHours[day].min = Math.min(
    moment(item.startDate).hours() * 60 + moment(item.startDate).minutes(),
    daysHours[day].min
  );
  daysHours[day].max = Math.max(
    moment(item.endDate).hours() * 60 + moment(item.endDate).minutes(),
    daysHours[day].max
  );
  daysHours[day].minutes = daysHours[day].max - daysHours[day].min;
});

console.log(daysHours);
```

The output of `console.log(daysHours)` in your example is

```
{
  2021-04-19: {
    min: 510
    max: 780
    minutes: 270
  }
}
```

270 minutes = 4.5 hours

If you can, I suggest you to import [moment-range](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment-range/v/1.0.2) and use it for this kind of tasks

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but object can contains range with differents day in a week : from monday to sunday

Comment: I assumed same day only in object not in all array. At the end daysHours has one key for every different day in the array

Comment: Yes, but sometimes, it not works : https://ibb.co/TK8Tqvh

Comment: If I use multiple range in a day, it's not work :(